# SQLAlchemy with_variant() not respecting custom column type

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy's `with_variant()` to use a custom column (decorated type) for the dialect variant, however implementations of `bind_expression` and `col_expression` are never called.

This is a small test case demonstrating this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import sqlalchemy.orm
import sqlalchemy.types


class CompressedLargeBinary(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        # No compress function in SQLite but we'll never get here
        return sqlalchemy.func.compress(bindvalue, type_=self)

    def column_expression(self, col):
        # No uncompress function in SQLite but we'll never get here
        return sqlalchemy.func.uncompress(col, type_=self)


SometimesCompressedLargeBinary = sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary().with_variant(CompressedLargeBinary(), "sqlite")

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    bar = sqlalchemy.Column("baz", SometimesCompressedLargeBinary, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.id = None
        self.bar = bar


def main():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///./file.db')
    connection = engine.connect()
    Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    model = Foo("quux")
    session.add(model)
    session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The expected behaviour is that the INSERT query fails as it uses functions unavailable in SQLite, however `bind_expression` and `col_expression` are never called to make the SQL-level changes to apply these functions.

Obviously I'm not expecting the INSERT queries to actually work in SQLite because those functions don't exist, but I've written the example this way to demonstrate that the SQL-level overrides are never getting called.

The real world use case for this is that I'm trying to have a variant type apply for MySQL that uses `COMPRESS()` and `UNCOMPRESS()` while for local testing with SQLite the data is stored unchanged.

SQLAlchemy version: 1.1.9

Reproduced in:

- Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.11.6
- Python 2.7.3 on Debian Wheezy